# Multiple Enums with same raw value

Tags: ios, enums, swift4

Following [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/stylemanager-for-your-ios-app-with-swift-30ecd7c6015e)  tutorial

I have defined to structure for using custom fonts in my app, 
but I am getting a weird error **Raw value for enum case is not unique**
Basically I am trying to have multiple enum case with same rawValue

My Code is as follows

```
struct FontManager {

    enum Font: String {
        case customBlack = "CustomFont-Black"
        case customBold = "CustomFont-Bold"
        case customMedium = "CustomFont-Medium"
        case customRegular = "CustomFont-Regular"

        enum Size: CGFloat {
            case navTitle = 20
            case drawerListItemBadgeActiveFont = 10
            case drawerHeaderTitle, formFiled = 16
            case drawerHeaderSubTitle, drawerListItemActive, drawerListItemInActive = 14
            case drawerHeaderEndText, formLabel = 12
            case sampleCase = 18    
        }

        func font(size:Size) -> UIFont {
            let fontSize = size.rawValue
            let fontName = self.rawValue
            return UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)!
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is image of error]

I am getting these error for any random number 15, 17, 18
Please suggest how can I solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you omit an explicit value for an enum case based on a number (which you have done for `drawerHeaderTitle`, `drawerHeaderSubTitle`, `drawerListItemActive`, and `drawerHeaderEndText`) the compiler is going to automatically increment the previous case's value by one and assign it to the new case.  So what you really have is:

```
case navTitle = 20
case drawerListItemBadgeActiveFont = 10
case drawerHeaderTitle /* = 11 */
case formFilled = 16
case drawerHeaderSubTitle /*= 17 */
case drawerListItemActive /*= 18*/
case drawerListItemInActive = 14
case drawerHeaderEndText /*= 15*/
case formLabel = 12
case sampleCase = 18 /* Duplicates drawerListItemBadgeActiveFont */
```

So, it seems like you want the enum's value to serve double duty as the font size.  You can't really do that due to the uniqueness constraint, but you could do this:

```
enum Font {
case navTitle
case drawerListItemBadgeActiveFont
case drawerHeaderTitle
case formFilled
case drawerHeaderSubTitle
case drawerListItemActive
case drawerListItemInActive
case drawerHeaderEndText
case formLabel
case sampleCase

  var size: CGFloat {
      switch self {
           case .navTitle: return 20
           case .drawerListItemBadgeActiveFont: return 11
           case .drawerHeaderTitle, formFilled: return 16
           // ...etc...
      }
  }
}
```

...and then use code like this to extract the size:

```
func someFunc(font: Font) {
     let size = font.size // 20 for navTitle, etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, enums with Raw value should have a unique value (let's imagine that you will initiate `Size(rawValue:26)` but you have two cases for this value `drawerHeaderTitle` and `formFiled` - isn't it?). You can use several options instead - one of it just add a computative property instead of using raw value:

```
enum Size {
    case navTitle, drawerHeaderTitle, formFiled ...

    ....
    var value: CGFloat {
        switch self:
            case .navTitle:
                return 20
            case .drawerHeaderTitle:
                fallthrough
            case .formFiled:
                return 26
           ...
    }
}

enum Font {
    func font(size:Size) -> UIFont {
        let fontSize = size.value //change rawValue to value
        let fontName = self.rawValue
        return UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)!
    }
}
```